# Calling functions in two different ways - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I'm very new to JavaScript, so my apologies if this answer is glaringly obvious or I'm barking up the wrong tree!

What's the difference in the following code snippets:

```
function primeAddNum(innerHTML) {
    return function() {
        addNum(innerHTML);
        return false;
    };
}
var func = primeAddNum(innerHTML);
```

The second one:

```
var func = function() {
        return function() {
            addNum(innerHTML);
            return false;
        };
}();
```

The top one works the way I'd like it to, but not the bottom, but that's not overly important to me. What I want to know is the logic behind each block, because I just can't see the difference!

Comment: I know this is not the question but having anonymous functions return another anonymous function is pretty incestual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the second block is that `innerHTML` is undefined there, since you're not passing it. They will become equivalent if you change it to:

```
var func = function(innerHTML) {
    return function() {
        addNum(innerHTML);
        return false;
    };
}(innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes much more sense now. Can't believe I've been pulling my hair out over this one now I've seen the answer.

Comment: Also consider what Esailija said: the second style, with the self-invoking function, is for one use only. You can't create new functions without repeating the whole thing. So, if you plan on reusing `primeAddNum`, use the first version.

Comment: This will not make it un-`undefined` if it really was `undefined`, you are just capturing `innerHTML` instead of relying on an outside reference. Which is of course good but depending on the code not necessary.

Comment: @Esailija I'm assuming `innerHTML` was just an example, not a global var (or anything in scope). The first snippet (which works according to OP) passes that as a parameter to the outer function. I just adjusted the second one to do the same, as I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work otherwise (again, OP states that the second version did not work).

Comment: Correct, I should have specified this. It is not a global variable but rather one that loops and changes dependent on a user event. Thanks to both anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well with the second one you can only create a `func` once. But with first one, you can create many:

```
var func1 = primeAddNum(innerHTML);
var func2 = primeAddNum(someOtherInnerHTML);
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no difference, you can use both without any problems